# Trying to run Python program from command prompt

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, cmd, command-line

Path must be messed up and I can't fix it.

In the command prompt I am trying to open and run a python program that I made in IDLE. I am running Python 3.8.5. According to Automate the Boring Stuff, I should just be able to do:

```
py birthdays.py
```

But when I do that I get:

```
C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe: can't open file 'birtdays.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

All of my scripts are located in: `C:\Users\henri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32`.

The only thing that I could think of is that it is going one step too far and searching in `python.exe` instead of just `Python38-32`. But Ii'm not even sure it works like that.

I tried to add the exact path using:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32
```

But when I do this and press enter nothing happens.

Comment: `python birtdays.py`?

Comment: Is the file `birthdays.py` or `birthdays.py`? Python is being launched just fine, it just can't see the file.  Are you calling `py birtdays.py` from the same directory that `birtdays.py` is in?

Comment: The path is only used for looking up the actual program being executed - `py` in your example.  Python itself is responsible for interpreting any further filenames on the command line - and it *doesn't* apply any sort of search path, a bare filename is going to be looked for in the current working directory only.  So you either need to supply a full path instead of just `birtdays.py`, or `cd` to the directory containing it before issuing your command.

Comment: `birthdays.py` is in `C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32`. So the only difference with that path and the error I am getting is the: `python.exe` at the end. @Josh

Comment: I see... that makes sense, thank you for your comment. So what exactly would I do if `birthdays.py` is located in `C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32` ? And if I have to type out some long path just to run the program wouldn't it be better to just open IDLE and run it from there? I thought running it directly from CMD was supposed to be quicker and easier. @jasonharper

Comment: It was *your* choice to put your scripts somewhere with an insanely long path.  Put them in `C:\Users\name\pyscripts\` perhaps - then you can use `py pyscripts\birthdays.py`, or use `cd pyscripts` followed by `py birthdays.py`.

Answer (score 0):

when I want to use CMD to run python scripts, I just use

```
cd\
```

to back the main root of drive C. then use

```
cd folderAddress
```

for several time until to reach the exact scrip containing folder. Finally, I type

```
python scriptName.py
```

Comment: This did work, thank you! But isn't the whole point of running a script from the CMD and not just opening up IDLE to make it simple and fast to run it? If I have to go find the full path every time I think that would be slower than IDLE. Are there other benefits to using CMD to run scripts?

Comment: I was using CMD to run several scripts simultaneously to parallelize and speed up simulations. But nowadays, I use Pycharm. because I can run several scripts and meanwhile debug another script, manage scripts and use local version control(it is a very useful tool in large projects).  So I recommend you to use an IDE instead of using CMD.

Answer (score 0):

In your command prompt type python.The output should be python 3.** (depending on your python version).

If you see the python version it's working fine. In command prompt navigate to the folder that you have your python file using **cmd** command. then type

> python birtdays.py

Don't forget the space after python.

Comment: When I run "python" in the CMD I get `'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` but then when I run "py" I get `Python 3.8.5 (tags/v3.8.5:580fbb0, Jul 20 2020, 15:43:08) [MSC v.1926 32 bit (Intel)] on win32. Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.` Maybe it is a version difference?

Comment: Seems like it. Try to add python to the path manually using the following link. https://datatofish.com/add-python-to-windows-path/ . if you still have problem try deleting all of your python versions and then install anaconda.